# only auto-reload session when I start vim with no parameter

Tags: vim

here's a piece of my ~/.vimrc file:

```
autocmd VimEnter * : call ReadSession()
autocmd VimLeave * : call SaveSession()
function SaveSession()
    execute 'mksession! ' . getcwd() . '/.session.vim'
endfunction
function ReadSession()
    let session_file = getcwd() . "/.session.vim"
    if filereadable( session_file )
        execute "so " . session_file
        if bufexists(1)
            for l in range(1, bufnr('$'))
                if bufwinnr(l) == -1
                    exec 'sbuffer ' . l
                endif
            endfor
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

So it will reload a session even  if I don't want it to
For example I call "vim 1.cpp" in a dirctory I once worked in(editing 2.cpp), then it will first show me 2.cpp
Can I modify the .vimrc so that if I pass parameters to vim, it won't read the session file? thanks!

EDITING:
I added a line

```
if (argc() > 0)
    exec 'bfirst'
endif
```

but it still don't work.

Comment: Did you try wrapping everything inside `ReadSession()` in an `if argc() == 0` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `argc()` is indeed the way to go. You can skip the execution of `ReadSession()` when parameters are passed:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | call ReadSession() | endif
```

Or put the condition into the `ReadSession()` function.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I think my solution 'bfirst' is better, because I won't lose history~ In the end I found that my problem is mistake exec for execute...